# Connection to Webpage and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, browser

I'm trying to create an application with tkinter, and I want the ability to connect it to a website and display what's there. It's sort of a web browser without the URL bar. Is it possible? If so, is there any documentation I could use? Do you have any source code I could learn from?

Comment: See [Grail](http://grail.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tkinter widget for displaying the contents of a web page.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can achieve the requirement is by creating a web page first with a url, and then connecting it to a tkinter widget.

for example:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

new = 1
url = "https://www.google.com"

def openweb():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)

Btn = Button(root, text = "This opens Google",command=openweb)
Btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```